# Fix for Chart.js removing Admin Bar

Tags: templates, javascript

I am using Chart.js within Wordpress by use of template the code removes/hides the admin bar. Has anyone ever incurred this, and how do you fix it?

```
function wpt_script_js(){
 wp_enqueue_script( 'Chart js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/Chart.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
 }
```

Comment: do you have some JavaScript error, and how do you inject Chart.js. Provide us te code?

Comment: No Javascript errors. The code works 100% correctly. Chart.js is enqueued using correct WordPress method.

Comment: I would like to duplicate the problem if possible. Can you send me the exact line how you enqueued the script, please?